# Echoing multiple variables with no space between them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a batch file

Is it possible for a FOR statement to echo some variables in a .txt file multiple times on the same line and WITHOUT leaving a space between them? How?

So far i have tried this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in test.txt do (echo | set /p d="%i">>new.txt )
```

Basically the test.txt contains a random number in each line and i want to echo these numbers as one in a new file. But it keeps putting spaces in between each of them.

Comment: `(FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in (test.txt) do @set /p "d=%i"<nul)>new.txt`

Comment: You must have trailing spaces in your test.txt file.  In my answer, I demonstrate this and show you how to strip trailing spaces effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a go at this.

```
@echo off
set str=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.txt) do set "str=!str!%%i"
echo|set /p str=!str!>>new.txt
```

note, the last line could be `echo !str!>>new.txt` but I simply used `echo|set` to eliminate any newline.

Answer (score 0):

## There must be trailing spaces in your source file.

To resolve you can use a couple of methods.

**1) Use Tokens=1 in your for /F loop**

Note this only works if there is only one value on the line, and it's the nth value (in this case n=1).

```
FOR /f "tokens=1" %i in (test.txt) do @(echo.| set /p "d=%~i">>new.txt )

Y:\>type new.txt
4912734109111317117319738888888888
```

**2) Use a second "for" loop to strip the trailing spaces.**

Note:  The method I chose will strip all spaces from the line, so if you have two numbers with a space between them on a line on purpose, the space will be removed.  If you prefer only to grab the 1st term or if you prefer to keep the space in such circumstances then additional changes could be made.

```
Y:\>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in (test.txt) do @(for %i in (%~i) DO @(echo.| set /p "d=%~i">>new.txt ) )

Y:\>type new.txt
491273410911131711731973658888888888
```

**Below I show in detail that the issue must be due to trailing spaces and how the new method correctly handles this:**

```
REM Initial Setup No Spaces:

Y:\>echo.>new.txt
Y:\>echo.4>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.9>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.12>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.7>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.34>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.10>>test.txt

REM Test Original Method and Result:

Y:\>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in (test.txt) do @(echo.| set /p "d=%~i">>new.txt )

Y:\>type new.txt
491273410

REM Clear Result and Add More values including ones with lots of spaces:

Y:\>echo.>new.txt
Y:\>echo. 9 >>test.txt
Y:\>echo. 11>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.13 >>test.txt
Y:\>echo.17>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.    11>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.            73              >>test.txt
Y:\>echo.19>>test.txt
Y:\>echo.            73           65   >>test.txt
Y:\>echo.8888888888>>test.txt

REM Test Original Method and Result:
Y:\>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in (test.txt) do @(echo.| set /p "d=%~i">>new.txt )

Y:\>type new.txt
4912734109 1113 171173              1973           65   8888888888

REM Reset Results File, Test New Method, and show results:

Y:\>echo.>new.txt

Y:\>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i in (test.txt) do @(for %I in (%~i) DO @(echo.| set /p "d=%~I">>new.txt ) )

Y:\>type new.txt
491273410911131711731973658888888888
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of any linefeeds in a file:

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

<nul >NoCRLF.txt (FOR /F useback^ delims^=^ tokens^=*^ eol^= %%L in ("test.txt") do set/p"=%%L")
```

---

## Limitations

- Blank lines will be skipped, but it isn't important here since all `\n` or `\r\n`s will be stripped anyways.
- Lines cannot start with `= <SPACE> <TAB> <NBSP>`